# Windows Forms Dead. Long life to WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms

In PDC sessions i see only Framework 4.0, Azure and WPF.

My all applications is in windows forms and asp.net (codebehind) and framework 2.0 or 3.5.  I see i'am obsolete, ok. But my questions is Windows Forms is dead, i need start migrate to WPF or Silverlight? or my Windows forms with Devexpress can leave more than 3 years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think I'd say WinForms is dead... is DOS dead?  Do you ever write a console app?  There's way to many programs out there on Windows (really the majority of them) that use WinForms for it to just die.  Remember Y2K and all those systems needing to be updated from Cobol (or was it Fortran?).  Personally, I'm migrating to WPF, but there's still a time and place for WinForms I believe... C++ is still being used even though we all have C# now, kind of the same concept I think.

Answer (score 11):

It's not really dead or alive -- more like undead.

Answer (score 4):

I've just installed VS2010 C# Express edition and there's still the option to create a WinForms project. I expect that the options still there in the full version too (I'm currently without an MSDN subscription so I can't get it at the moment).

So I think that there's still life in the technology.

By all means move to WPF or Silverlight, but do it because they offer you something you can't get from WinForms.

Comment: "do it because they offer you something you can't get from WinForms"... and has more value for you than the cost of moving.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms is no more dead than VBScript is dead. And I'm currently working with some fairly atrocious classic ASP VBSCript code, so I can assure you, it's not dead either (alas).

Win Forms will be around pretty much until Microsoft drops Win32 entirely, and even then it'll still be around in legacy systems for several more years.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many differences between these two and probably it would be a good idea to establish some roadmap in order to migrate your application. There are many hundreds of websites for their comparison, but in order to answer your question, I suggest to start a new branch and start migrating while supporting your current models. With your current one you wouldn't have that much of problems either.